# Window Auto sizing when adding grid row via button

Tags: wpf

I have a window with a basic grid in it and a button that adds a grid row and a user control to the grid. all user controls are the same size. How do i automatically increase the size of the window for each user control that is added.

XAML for window:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Height="22" x:Name="AddRow" Click="AddRow_Click">
                <TextBlock Text="Add Skill"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Height="22" x:Name="Close" Click="Close_Click" >
                <TextBlock Text="Exit"/>
            </Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Height="22" x:Name="Minimize" Click="Minimize_Click" >
                <TextBlock Text="Minimize"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>


            <Grid x:Name="SkillGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">                
                <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>


    </DockPanel>
```

Xaml for usercontrol:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">

        <StackPanel>           
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                    <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=grid1,Path=ActualWidth,Converter={StaticResource RestrictedWidthOverflowConverter}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Left"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>    

            <Grid Margin="3" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="AgentWindow" Click="AgentWindow_Click">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="button" Text="agent"/>
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Open Full Agent List" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Open Aux Only" Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Margin="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="TeamNameText" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Team Name"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SkillNum"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="Skill Number" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="15"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="3" Grid.Column="2">
                <Image Margin="8, 8, 8, 8" x:Name="CallImage" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="3" Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="WaitTimeText" Text="Wait Time"/>

                <TextBlock Margin="5" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15" x:Name="AgentAvailableData" Text="Available Number"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="15" x:Name="WaitTimeData" Text="Wait Time"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Margin="3" Grid.Column="4">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="HotSeat" Text="HotSeat" MouseDown="HotSeat_MouseDown" MouseLeave="HotSeat_MouseLeave"/>
            </Grid>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Code to add user Control:

```
private void AddRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {                
            RowDefinition c1 = new RowDefinition();
            c1.Height = new GridLength(20, GridUnitType.Star);
            SkillGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(c1);    

            var uc = new ScoreSingleLineDisplayUCV2();
            SkillGrid.Children.Add(uc);
            Grid.SetRow(uc, SkillGrid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
        }
```

Comment: testing this right now

Comment: so i used this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height; in the button click...unfortunately it didn't have the completely desired effect. I have a image in the usercontrol that is being added that used margin and the grid to control the sizing... but the line of code above made the image explode to full screen size. i guess it is a dupliate because it had the desired effect but failed in my case. looking for a work around.

Comment: I actually just removed the image. its kind of an eye sore anyway. i'm not sure how to mark this as a duplicate, if you could do that it would be wonderful!